# How to specify https scheme in Swashbuckle for .NET Core

Tags: swagger, swashbuckle

How can I specify `https` schema in the `.NET Core` version of Swashbuckle? In ASP.NET version I could do

```
.EnableSwagger(c =>
{
  c.Schemes(new[] { "https" });
}
```

but I don't see anything similar as part of AddSwaggerGen.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just implement the interface `IDocumentFilter` and use it in `Startup.cs`:

```
public class TestFilter : IDocumentFilter
{
    public void Apply(SwaggerDocument swaggerDoc, DocumentFilterContext context)
    {
        swaggerDoc.Schemes = new string[] { "http" };
    }
}

// Startup.cs
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
     c.SwaggerDoc("v2", new Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.Info 
                        { Title = "My API", Version = "v2" });
     c.DocumentFilter<TestFilter>();
 });
```

Comment: When I use this code `swaggerDoc.Schemes` does not resolve.

Comment: There is no longer a "Schemes" property, this does not work with the latest version of swashbuckle

Answer (score 4):

The solution from @marius worked for me, except when launched locally. As he rightly points out that httpReq.Host.Host will omit port number. As an improvement, the snippet below keeps the port number and works both on localhost as well as hosted API.
NOTE: my localhost is on HTTP

Nuget Package version: Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 6.0.7

```
app.UseSwagger(options =>
{
    options.PreSerializeFilters.Add((swagger, httpReq) =>
    {
        var scheme = httpReq.Host.Host.StartsWith("localhost", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ? "http" : "https";
        swagger.Servers = new List<OpenApiServer>() {new OpenApiServer() {Url = $"{scheme}://{httpReq.Host}"}};
    });
});
```

Comment: When I add this code I receive Could not load file or assembly 'Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen, Version=6.1.0.0..' even if Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.dll is installed and in place. Both on dev and in production

Answer (score 2):

In Swashbuckle.AspNetCore v 6.0.7 you can do this:

```
                app.UseSwagger(c => {
                    c.PreSerializeFilters.Add((swagger, httpReq) =>
                    {
                        swagger.Servers = new List<OpenApiServer> { new OpenApiServer { Url = $"https://{httpReq.Host.Host}" } };
                    });
                });
```

Please note: the above example assumes port 443, you will have to provide your https port number as well if this is not the case.

Comment: This is very clean, but for some reason my IDE did not auto-import the OpenApiServer. If anyone else gets an error about that try `using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;` at the top of the file with your other using statements. Also a bit of white-space never hurt with new-lines after those curly / face brackets :wink:.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code at swagger latest version:

```
 public class SwaggerDocumentFilter : IDocumentFilter

    {

        private readonly string _swaggerDocHost;


        public SwaggerDocumentFilter(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)

        {

            var host = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Host.Value;

            var scheme = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Scheme;

            _swaggerDocHost = $"{scheme}://{host}";

        }


        public void Apply(OpenApiDocument swaggerDoc, DocumentFilterContext context)

        {

            swaggerDoc.Servers.Add(new OpenApiServer { Url = _swaggerDocHost });

        }

    }
```

If you want to set _swaggerDocHost="https://sitename".